# What does these logs means? (DHCPREQUEST)

Tags: security, logs

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as my OS. For safety purposes, I'm always checking the logs to see any strange thing.
Today, I have found something that (probably) never happened to me:

```
Jun 11 23:33:59 nori-hidamari dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.3 on wlan0 to 192.168.0.1 port 67 (xid=0x21f83c60)
Jun 11 23:33:59 nori-hidamari dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.3 from 192.168.0.1
Jun 11 23:33:59 nori-hidamari dhclient: bound to 192.168.0.3 -- renewal in 3175 seconds.
Jun 11 23:33:59 nori-hidamari NetworkManager[979]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed reboot -> renew
Jun 11 23:33:59 nori-hidamari NetworkManager[979]: <info>   address 192.168.0.3
Jun 11 23:33:59 nori-hidamari NetworkManager[979]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
Jun 11 23:33:59 nori-hidamari NetworkManager[979]: <info>   gateway 192.168.0.1
Jun 11 23:33:59 nori-hidamari NetworkManager[979]: <info>   nameserver '189.7.80.15'
Jun 11 23:33:59 nori-hidamari NetworkManager[979]: <info>   nameserver '189.7.80.16'
Jun 11 23:33:59 nori-hidamari NetworkManager[979]: <info>   nameserver '201.6.4.116'
Jun 11 23:33:59 nori-hidamari NetworkManager[979]: <info>   domain name 'domain.name'
Jun 11 23:33:59 nori-hidamari dbus[541]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Jun 11 23:33:59 nori-hidamari dbus[541]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
```

Can someone tell me what's happened here? Please note that I saw this on syslog

Thank you guys for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This person asked [pretty much the same question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94401/understanding-var-log-messages-entries) on Unix & Linux stack exchange.

Here is the start of the answer, probably more efficient for you to click over to the link.

First 3 lines are messages from dhclient which:

```
sent a DHCP request to the router
received DHCP lease
set up the interface
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will take a better look at what is DHCP. But, just to be sure, those logs means that everything is normal, right?

Comment: I am no expert, but from reading the other question, I think so.